# How to control 400 RGB LEDs individually?

Tags: led, rgb

I've got a little home project that I want to start. I don't have really have any experience in this field. So be gentle.

I need control up to 400 RGB LEDs individually.
They only need to function in 3 states - off, red, blue.
I would position them in a grid layout and each state would represent a different position.

Any advise anyone can give.
Would be great.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you be more specific how or with what you want to control them? Otherwise, we don't know what kind of answers you want. For example, you can just put 400 SPDT switches to have control of each LED. Which LEDs those are, which voltage they use, how much they consume current, do they have a built in controller or are they bare LED dies, how many will be turned on at once, is multiplexing allowed...

Comment: Strips with individually addressable LEDs are widely enable. Perform search and optimize by most important parameters, like cost, brightness etc.

Comment: Ah, let me see.  I think you can try a stripe of 400 WS2812B RGB LEDs electrically daisy chained, and physically laid out in a grid, with LED to LED socially distance of at most 5 meters. And you only need one wire, one GPIO pin to control all 400 individually addressed RGB LEDs. The one wire communication protocol uses async NRZ, and each RGB LED is a smart LED, with built in signal reshaping circuits. Max 30fps, 800kHz bit rate. Here is a reference: https://i.imgur.com/fHON6Bv.jpg. And a product sheet: https://nl.aliexpress.com/item/2036819167.html. Good luck. Cheers.

Comment: Just buy this https://nl.aliexpress.com/item/4001083998241.html?spm=a2g0z.12010612.8148356.1.52f94396jhyyZg

Comment: If you are in the USA, and you want the LEDs close together: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B088BTYJH6  Make your own array from strips if you want them spaced farther apart.